# How to find tray icon position using Shell_NotifyIconGetRect?

Tags: delphi

```
type
  NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER = record
    cbSize  : DWORD;
    hWnd    : HWND;
    uID     : UINT;
    guidItem: TGUID;
end;
  PNOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER = ^NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER;


function Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(const _in: NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER; var _out: TRECT): HRESULT; stdcall;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function Shell_NotifyIconGetRect; external 'Shell32.dll' name 'Shell_NotifyIconGetRect';

procedure TForm1.SettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
var R: TRect;
    S: NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER;
begin

  FillChar(S, SizeOf(S), #0);
  S.cbSize := SizeOf(NOTIFYICONIDENTIFIER);
  S.hWnd := form1.TextTrayIcon1.Handle;
  S.uID := ??????;

  if Shell_NotifyIconGetRect(S, R) = S_OK then
  begin
    Showmessage('OK!');

  end
  else Showmessage('ERROR!');

end;
```

I'm using Delphi 7 and [CoolTrayIcon](https://torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=cooltrayicon&Title=Yes) component. My goal is to find tray icon position in order to correctly align form.
QUESTION: What do I have to add here? 
S.uID := ??????;
I can't find anything related with uID in TextTrayIcon component.

Comment: You need to find the ID of your icon, or its GUID if that is how it was registered. In order to get that you need to consult the documentation for CoolTrayIcon. Rather easier would be just to call `Shell_NotifyIcon` to create your notification icon.

Comment: In the constructor of `TCoolTrayIcon`: `FIconID := Cardinal(Self);` And later `IconData.uId := FIconID;`

Comment: I still have no idea how to retrieve that data.

Comment: So, don't try to use the component under x64 ........

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera, `S.uID := Cardinal(form1.TextTrayIcon1);`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the OP is using Delphi 7, which does not support 64bit development. The author doesn't report the component supports past D2006.  64bit was added in XE2.

Comment: @Remy Yes. And this code had better not be used in x64.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera: since you have the source code for `TCoolTrayIcon`, you might consider tweaking it to add a new public property to return the generated ID, eg: `property IconID: Cardinal read FIconID;` or `property IconID: Cardinal read IconData.uId;`  For that matter, you might also consider adding a new public method, like `function GetIconRect: TRect;`,  that calls `Shell_NotifyIconGetRect()` using the HWND and ID from the internal `IconData`.